# Could not find react-redux context value when using useSelector()

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am new to react and am trying to understand why I'm seeing this error:

```
Error: could not find react-redux context value; please ensure the component is wrapped in a <Provider>
```

**App.js**

```
export default function App() {
  const selectedNumber = useSelector(selectChosenNumber) // This line causes the error

  function pickedNumberHandler() {
    console.log("called")
  }

  let screen = <StartGameScreen />;

  pickedNumberHandler()

  store.subscribe(pickedNumberHandler)

  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <LinearGradient colors={['#4e0329', '#ddb52f']} style={styles.rootScreen}>
        <ImageBackground
          source={require('./assets/images/background.png')}
          resizeMode="cover"
          style={styles.rootScreen}
          imageStyle={{opacity: 0.15}}
        >
          {screen}
        </ImageBackground>
      </LinearGradient>
    </Provider>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  rootScreen: {
    flex: 1,
  }
})
```

**chosenNumberReducer.ts**

```
export const chosenNumberSlice = createSlice({
  name: "chosenNumber",
  initialState: {
    value: ""
  },
  reducers: {
    pickNumber: (state, action) => {
      state.value = action.payload
    }
  }
})

export const { pickNumber } = chosenNumberSlice.actions
export const selectChosenNumber = state => state.chosenNumber.value;
export default chosenNumberSlice.reducer
```

I'm trying to listen to changes in state but can't seem to access the values in app.js.

Comment: You Should use `Provider` in Upper level component (i.e. `Index.js`). After that, you can use `useSelector` in this component.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to move your logic outside of App. When it says `please ensure the component is wrapped in a <Provider>` it means that the component you are using the `useSelector` in, needs to be under `<Provider>` which in this case means App.js.

So App.js should contain only

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <NewComponent .../>
    </Provider>
  );
}
```

And NewComponent.js should contain rest of the logic.